# Load a text file into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

I have 256 x 8 text file, i want to fetch it into np array(256,8), with int cast

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2.cv2 as cv2
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt')
```

then i get this error:
could not convert string to float: '200.35,159.32,200.35,113.74,245.48,113.74,245.48,159.32'

Comment: The default delimiter in `loadtxt` is `white space`, not comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the strings into its separate values. `loadtxt` has a parameter that does this:

```
np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt', delimiter=',')
```

This splits each row at the comma so that each number can be read as a separate value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a suggestion, consider linking to the relevant docs so that users can see up-to-date information about the keyword args and know where to find information later :)